# combinatorics license plate question

Tags: combinatorics

So, for this example a license plate is made up of:

- three different digits that are prime
- three letters from {a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h} but two must be the same and the third one different
- two symbols from {!, @, #, $} that can be the same or different

I understand the 1st and 3rd bullet, but for the second my teacher said it is $$3 \times 8 \times 7$$ where 3 picks the place the one letter appears, and you can choose that letter 8 ways, while 7 is choosing the repeated letter. I don't understand the 3. For my answer I got $$8 \times 7$$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The $3$ comes from the fact that for any selection $\{a,a,b\}$ there are three possible permutations: $\{a,a,b\},\{a,b,a\},\{b,a,a\}$.